# Several appdomains calling the same unmanaged dll

Tags: c#, .net, dll, appdomain

Our .NET 3.5 C# application creates multiple appdomains. Each appdomain loads the same unmanaged 3rd party dll. This dll reads a configuration file upon initialization. If the configuration changes during runtime, the dll must be unloaded and loaded again. This dll is not in our scope to rewrite correctly.

Does each appdomain have access to a separtate copy of this unmanaged dll, or does Windows keep one copy of the dll and maintain a usage count? If the latter is is the case, how do we get each instance of the unmanaged dll to reflect its unique configuration?

Comment: When you say 'Load', do you mean via `LoadLibrary`?

Comment: Suggest you say more about the exact circumstances in which the configuration file changes : what changes it : are you implying that at arbitrary intervals you create a new appdomain, and then read the configuration file which may have been changed by the application-in-progress ? So any time the configuration file changes, all dlls loaded with a previous config file must be unloaded and re-loaded ? So a given 'dll has no ability to re-configure itself when notified the config file has changed ? Sounds like a design nightmare.

Comment: Leppie - by "Load" I do mean LoadLibrary.
BillW - I agree, this is a design nightmare that is out of our scope of control. We need to work with it for now. The configuration file changes whenever a user needs to switch between "projects" (not important what that is in this context) and it can happen at any time.

Answer (score 0):

I think unmanaged dlls are loaded only once per process by the OS, so every app-domain will have the same loaded instance. To unload a dll, use the FreeLibrary function. However, since multiple app-domains are likely to have loaded the dll, there is no guarantee that FreeLibrary from one app-domain will actually free/unload the dll.

As BillW says, this seems like a design nightmare to me too!